# how to place icon for firefox addon installation / restart message screen?

Tags: firefox-addon

I am writing a firefox addon. I have placed an icon for it which appears on installation screen. after installation when I am asked to restart firefox the icon does not appear on the screen which says “Restart Firefox to complete your changes”
After installation again the icon starts appearing.

How to make the icon appear on the screen which says “Restart Firefox to complete your changes” ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hey. I'm looking for the same thing. How did you do to customize the icon during the installation of the extension?